# combine urls in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say I have an url that looks like this:
play.game.online/snake/14/206524
and
play.game.online/pacman/14/206524

And have other urls like:
play.game.online/snake/18/741285
play.game.online/snake/24/238642
and
play.game.online/pacman/28/747585
play.game.online/pacman/45/245842

Now I want GA to show all the data that is binded to those url's to show up as:
play.game.online/snake/
and
play.game.online/pacman/

I have read a few things about filters but I really can't figure it out and in desperate need of some help.

Really hope someone can help me out

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try an Advanced Filter (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en):

[image]

Note that in your example, you have the hostname included as well, so you would have another filter after the Advanced Filter that would append the hostname to the path, giving you:

`play.online.com/snake/` or `play.online.com/pacman/`.